# Javascript on mobile menu doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, mobile, menu

I have a problem with a mobile menu toggle not working on this site: http://www.toscanzahoeve.be

The mobile menu toggle (displays below 975 px) doesn't work. The javascript works for the toggle itself (gets the class 'activated') but not for the 'nav' element below (which style should switch from 'display: none' to 'display: block').

This is a site where it does work: http://downloadaproduct.com/

And this is the javascript code:

```
( function( window, $, undefined ) {
'use strict';

$( 'nav' ).before( '<button class="menu-toggle" role="button" aria-pressed="false"></button>' ); // Add toggles to menus
$( 'nav .sub-menu' ).before( '<button class="sub-menu-toggle" role="button" aria-pressed="false"></button>' ); // Add toggles to sub menus

// Show/hide the navigation
$( '.menu-toggle, .sub-menu-toggle' ).on( 'click', function() {
    var $this = $( this );
    $this.attr( 'aria-pressed', function( index, value ) {
        return 'false' === value ? 'true' : 'false';
    });

    $this.toggleClass( 'activated' );
    $this.next( 'nav, .sub-menu' ).slideToggle( 'fast' );

});

})( this, jQuery );
```

I spent hours trying to resolve this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Stefaan

Comment: Can you be more specific so we can effectively help you? What does "doesn't work" mean? Did you get an error? If so, what line is it on and what is the exact error message?

Comment: You aren't including jQuery (so you can't `slideToggle`) AND your select will only find the `nav` and not the `.sub-menu`, you also can't use `next`, but even if you did include jQuery, next searches subsequent siblings whereas the `nav` element is prior to `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified what "doesn't work" about your code, but I do see this:

```
$this.attr( 'aria-pressed', function( index, value ) {
    return 'false' === value ? 'true' : 'false';
});
```

Here, you are setting the value of the `aria-pressed` attribute to a function (as if this were an event handler, which it is not). The function will not actually execute in this scenario - the entire function simply becomes the value of the attribute.

According to the [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties), this attribute can have the following values:

- **true/false** : Value representing either true or false, with a default
  "false" value.
- **tristate** : Value representing true or false, with an intermediate
  "mixed" value. Default value is "false" unless otherwise specified.
- **true/false/undefined** : Value representing true or false, with > a
  default "undefined" value indicating the state or property is not 
  relevant.
- **ID reference** : Reference to the ID of another element in the same
  document
- **ID reference** : list A list of one or more ID references.
- **integer** : A numerical value without a fractional component.
- **number** : Any real numerical value. string Unconstrained value type.
- **token** : One of a limited set of allowed values.
- **token list** : A list of one or more tokens.

As you can see, a function is not acceptable as the value.

I think what you want is the **result** of the body of your function (which will return `true` or `false`, both acceptable values), but not a function itself:

```
$this.attr( 'aria-pressed', ('false' === value ? 'true' : 'false'));
```